# SSR Switches Off Intermittently By Itself

Tags: power-electronics, solid-state-relay

I have a 24 ~ 380 V 100 Amp AC relay. It can be driven between 3 ~ 32 V, and I'm using a Raspberry pi to drive it with 5 V.

The relay has a red LED that indicates it is "on". When checking up on the relay, I've noticed its off half of the time while the Pi is still running and supplying 5 V. 
I don't know if it goes off and comes on by itself again - but when I pull out the positive and negative wires from the relay and wait a minute before re-attaching them, the relay works for a short while before going off again.

I've had the relay for only a few weeks with a max current of 220 V AC. Can anyone tell me what could he wrong with the relay?

Comment: Have you measured the drive voltage from the R'Pi output to the SSR input terminal? You are probably very close to the minimum drive voltage.  .....by the way 220 V AC is not a current draw.....you have not specified the current you are drawing on the load side.

Comment: @Jac Creasey Yes I have. The drive current stays stable at 5V but the relay would be off. The minimum drive voltage is 3 V. The load is 220 V.

Comment: @Jnr - (a) Please supply a link to the datasheet for your specific SSR. (b) Where did you buy it? (c) You've misunderstood *Jack Creasey*'s question about the load: You've given the load's *voltage*; he asked about the load's *current*. Have you measured *that*? (if so, how, exactly?) (d) What is the actual load? (e) You'll need to supply a wiring diagram of your connections since the connections to RPi and "5V" are confusing. For example, the RPi GPIOs do not supply 5V when driven "high". (f) "*when I pull out the wires from the relay*" Which wires, exactly? Again, a clear diagram will help.

Comment: @SamGibson Oh yes, of course. The max current load being applied is about 60 Amps (well within the relays capability of 100 Amp). The Gpio pin is set to Low and when measuring its voltage is about 5.1 V. The wires I disconnect are the positive and negative that drive the relay - the rest of the wires stay in tact. Here is the link to the SSD https://www.robotics.org.za/SSR100A I will draw a diagram in the morning. Its a fairly simple circuit.

Comment: Sorry, here's the link again    https://www.robotics.org.za/electronic-components-general/relays/SSR100A-AC

Comment: I assume your SSR has a very high likelihood that it's a fake. Fotek don't make a  unit that is marked as 100 A: http://www.fotek.com.hk/page1e.htm    ....who knows what you have.  Look on the Internet for fake SSR's, they are endemic.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the relay is [a fake](https://www.ul.com/newsroom/publicnotices/ul-warns-of-solid-state-relay-with-counterfeit-ul-recognition-mark-release-13pn-52/). Thanks for the help and to Jack Creasey for pointing this out. I am going to contact the seller for a refund.